# Dropdown Icon Group in expo

Tags: javascript, react-native, custom-component, expo, android-icons

I saw this the following icon Handling in some apps

[image]

[image]

Is there a way to expo to do this?
I didn't find any other way than including custom Components, which is not possible in expo so far.
So the only way i see working would be detaching.
I would prefere not to detcach from expo, as it offers many comforts in App devellopment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still looking into the problem i found a Solution.

There is an component which is called Floating-Action-Button, that is compatible with expo.

Here is the link of the git with an expo example as well.

https://github.com/santomegonzalo/react-native-floating-action

Hope this helps someone else comming across the same problem.